# Fetch Bounces Failure, Error message: Unknown api version

Tags: api, failure, bounce-processing

For some reason, the fetch bounce api method is unrecognized (Fetch Bounces     Finished execution of Fetch Bounces with result: Failure, Error message: Unknown api version).

not sure if related to recent php upgrade (8.1) or last Civicrm upgrade (5.66.2). Last functioning fetch bounces (October 27) returned api method as Parameters parsed (and passed to API method):
a:2:{s:7:"version";i:3;s:20:"is_create_activities";s:1:"0";}

Current failure log message:
Fetch Bounces
Entity: Job Action: fetch_bounces
Summary: Starting execution of Fetch Bounces
Details:
Parameters raw (from db settings): is_create_activities=0
Parameters parsed (and passed to API method): a:0:{}

Full message:
Starting execution of Fetch Bounces

Any help appreciated!

Comment: I have the same problem ? Any solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might have the same problem, I'm not sure. I've got a client recently updated to php8.1 and civicrm 5.67.1. Their bounce processing (which has been running for many years), now seems to be ignoring everything.

Specifically, the bounce mail is arriving into their mailbox (i.e I see it in the new folder) and the the bounce job runs and it all gets put into the .INBOX.CiviMail.ignored/cur directory, and shows no bounces.

That suggests that there's a parsing of the message that has started failing. I'm pretty sure it's not the php8.1 upgrade, since I have other clients without this symptom that are upgraded to php8.1.

This might be the same issue, it has a PR against it:

https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/4775

https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/28354

Update: yes, that PR resolved it. After applying the patch, I moved all the messages that were in the ignored mailbox into the new folder and reran the job and all kinds of new bounces showed up.

```
mv .INBOX.CiviMail.ignored/cur/* new/
```

And it's fixed in 5.67.3

Update:

This related issue looks to be closer to what you're experiencing: https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/2801

That one doesn't have a specific resolution, though it's identified as related.

Comment: I updated to 6.67.3, moved all IGNORED messages to INBOX, ran fetch_bounces, but received the same error:
Parameters raw (from db settings): 
is_create_activities=0
Parameters parsed (and passed to API method): 
a:0:{}
Full message: 
Finished execution of Fetch Bounces with result: Failure, Error message: Unknown api version

Is it fixed in 5.68??

Comment: I think your issue stems from the same time/code, but might be different. Take a look at this issue instead and see if it's relevant: https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/2801

Comment: Alternatively, maybe it's just a cache clearing issue? It certainly seems to be an odd symptom, i.e. the 'api version' error.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, @alandixon, but the issue 2801 was not relevant. Since Bounces aren't being fetched, they aren't being recorded at all, not even incorrectly. I varnished the cache on the server as well as within Civi and the CMS, but still the same error. Any other ideas???

Comment: I'm going to guess that the "unknown api version" applies to some api call generated as a side effect of the is_create_activities=0 parameter. Can you test this hypothesis? If you call the job without that parameter and it works, at least you've narrowed down the issue ... e.g. maybe you have some extension related to activities that isn't compatible the new version of civi.

Comment: the fetch_bounce job works without is_create_activities=0 parameter and with is_create_activities=1 parameter. how will is_create_activities=1 parameter affect contacts? i read there might be a problem: https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/2800

Comment: Ah, excellent! I have not experienced issue 2800, it looks like it might be specific to the use of VERP, and in any case, might be fixed, and is at worst an annoyance.

Comment: Thanks for all your help @alandixon! I will mark this as "answered," but if I run into problems, I will post again.